# SVG polygon fill is hiding my text labels

Tags: css, svg, polygon

For some reason when I add a white fill to the polygon, the text elements dont show. I tried using z-index to bring the text labels above but still. The text elements are black. If I set the polygon fills to none, the text labels show.

My fiddle (with original issue):
https://jsfiddle.net/omarel/qznxd4vo/1/

UPDATE: Based on the right answer below, this is the updated working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/omarel/qznxd4vo/5/

```
<style type="text/css">
.st0{fill:red;}
.st3 {fill:#fff;stroke:#58595B;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
.st3:hover {
    fill:red;cursor:pointer;
}
</style>
    <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="619px"
         height="587px" viewBox="0 0 619 587" style="enable-background:new 0 0 619 587;" xml:space="preserve">

    <g id="labels">
        <g>
            <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 459.8574 312.0654)" class="st0">pool</text>
        </g>
        <g>
            <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 456.687 178.0654)" class="st0">201</text>
        </g>
        <g>
            <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 324.7412 178.0654)" class="st0">202</text>
        </g>
        <g>
            <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 241.1572 178.0654)" class="st0">203</text>
        </g>
        <g>
            <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 181.8091 178.0654)" class="st0">204</text>
        </g>
        <g>
            <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 117.1631 178.0654)" class="st0">205</text>
        </g>
        <g>
            <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 459.9531 65.0654)" class="st0 ">206</text>
        </g>
        <g>
            <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 343.7593 65.0654)" class="st0">207</text>
        </g>
        <g>
            <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 229.0552 65.0654)" class="st0">208</text>
        </g>
        <g>
            <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 117.9531 65.0654)" class="st0">209</text>
        </g>
        <g>
            <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 31.687 65.0654)" class="st0">210</text>
        </g>
        <g>
            <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 69.3291 270.0654)" class="st0">211</text>
        </g>
        <g>
            <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 67.8833 345.0654)" class="st0 st1 st2">212</text>
        </g>
        <g>
            <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 127.2993 440.5654)" class="st0 st1 st2">213</text>
        </g>
        <g>
            <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 198.4512 440.5654)" class="st0 st1 st2">214</text>
        </g>
        <g>
            <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 302.3052 440.5654)" class="st0 st1 st2">215</text>
        </g>
        <g>
            <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 401.0952 440.5654)" class="st0 st1 st2">216</text>
        </g>
        <g>
            <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 522.4014 440.5654)" class="st0 st1 st2">217</text>
        </g>
        <g>
            <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 21.6973 444.0654)" class="st0 st1 st2">218</text>
        </g>
        <g>
            <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 66.5952 548.5654)" class="st0 st1 st2">219</text>
        </g>
        <g>
            <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 204.7412 548.5654)" class="st0 st1 st2">220</text>
        </g>
        <g>
            <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 325.3833 548.5654)" class="st0 st1 st2">221</text>
        </g>
        <g>
            <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 420.437 548.5654)" class="st0 st1 st2">222</text>
        </g>
        <g>
            <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 522.853 548.5654)" class="st0 st1 st2">223</text>
        </g>
    </g>
    <g id="units">
        <a href="#" class="link"><polygon class="st3" points="404.75,274 404.75,342 436.75,342 436.75,357 465.75,357 465.75,342.75 564.25,334.75 580.5,281.5 
            465.5,272.75 465.75,259.25 436.5,259.25 436.75,274  "/></a>
        <polygon class="st3" points="593.333,203.333 523,9.333 219.667,20 219.667,31 14.333,31 14.333,201 28.667,201 14.333,399 
            14.333,578 606.333,578 606.333,399.667 432.667,399.667 432.667,392.5 418.75,388.25 399.75,399.5 313.25,399.5 313.25,392.75 
            293.5,388.5 288,399.75 131,399.75 131,200.75 289.25,200.75 289.25,213.5     "/>
        <polygon class="st3" points="570.747,141.031 512.167,141.031 512.167,139.333 493,139.333 493,120 478.333,120 478.333,122.667 
            461.667,122.667 461.667,143.5 412.667,143.5 412.667,120 386,120 386,210.32 593.333,203.333  "/>
        <polygon class="st3" points="570.747,141.031 512.167,141.031 512.167,139.333 493,139.333 493,104.167 461.667,104.167 
            461.667,95.5 446.833,95.5 446.833,106.5 415.167,106.5 415.167,13.09 523,9.333   "/>
        <path class="st3" d="M415.167,106.5"/>
        <polygon class="st3" points="415.167,13.09 415.167,106.5 344.667,106.5 344.667,104.333 331,104.333 331,106.5 310.333,106.5 
            310.333,95.5 294.333,95.5 294.333,17.375    "/>
        <polyline class="st3" points="294.333,17.375 294.333,106.5 233.167,106.5 233.167,104.167 219.667,104.167 219.667,106.5 
            201.167,106.5 201.167,95.333 184.667,95.333 184.667,31 219.667,31   "/>
        <polygon class="st3" points="184.667,95.333 168.083,95.333 168.083,106.5 160.333,106.5 160.333,104.083 146.917,104.083 
            146.917,106.5 78.75,106.5 78.75,80.083 75.917,80.083 75.917,31 184.667,31   "/>
        <polygon class="st3" points="386,135 368.333,135 368.333,120 322,120 322,122.25 308.5,122.25 308.5,120 303.25,120 
            303.25,130.667 286.417,130.667 286.417,164.5 289.25,164.5 289.25,213.5 386,210.32   "/>
        <polygon class="st3" points="286.417,130.667 270.25,130.667 270.25,120 258.75,120 258.75,122.25 245.25,122.25 245.25,120 
            218.667,120 218.667,200.75 289.25,200.75 289.25,164.5 286.417,164.5     "/>
        <polygon class="st3" points="218.667,200.75 154.917,200.75 154.917,171.333 163.583,171.333 163.583,120 181.583,120 
            181.583,122.333 195,122.333 195,120 202.167,120 202.167,131.333 218.667,131.333     "/>
        <polygon class="st3" points="154.917,200.75 154.917,171.333 163.583,171.333 163.583,131 146.667,131 146.667,122.417 
            131.667,122.417 131.667,146.333 112.5,146.333 112.5,172.833 88.667,172.833 88.667,242.167 131,242.167 131,200.75    "/>
        <polygon class="st3" points="75.917,31 14.333,31 14.333,201 71.167,201 71.167,172.667 48.417,172.667 48.417,103.75 
            71.667,103.75 71.667,106.5 78.75,106.5 78.75,80.083 75.917,80.083   "/>
        <polygon class="st3" points="71.167,201 28.667,201 21.513,299.826 59.333,299.826 59.333,297.831 89.917,297.831 89.917,307.914 
            131,307.914 131,242.167 88.667,242.167 88.667,186.331 71.167,186.331    "/>
        <polyline class="st3" points="88.667,172.667 71.167,172.667 71.167,169.915 69.417,169.915 69.417,124.915 71.917,124.915 
            71.917,119.331 58.25,119.331 58.25,103.75 71.667,103.75 71.667,106.5 146.917,106.5 146.917,104.083 160.333,104.083 
            160.333,106.5 219.667,106.5 219.667,104.167 233.167,104.167 233.167,106.5 331,106.5 331,104.333 344.667,104.333 344.667,106.5 
            461.833,106.5 461.833,104.167 478.25,104.167 478.25,122.667 461.667,122.667 461.667,120 322,120 322,122.25 308.5,122.25 
            308.5,120 258.75,120 258.75,122.25 245.25,122.25 245.25,120 195,120 195,122.333 181.583,122.333 181.583,120 146.75,120 
            146.75,122.417 131.667,122.417 131.667,119.331 88.667,119.331 88.667,172.667    "/>
        <line class="st3" x1="71.917" y1="122.831" x2="88.667" y2="122.831"/>
        <line class="st3" x1="112.5" y1="146.333" x2="112.5" y2="119.331"/>
        <polygon class="st3" points="131,375.625 86,375.625 86,393.125 89.25,393.125 89.25,409 67.625,409 67.625,375.625 
            29.375,375.625 29.375,372.875 16.26,372.875 21.513,299.826 59.333,299.826 59.333,297.831 89.917,297.831 89.917,307.914 
            131,307.914     "/>
        <polygon class="st3" points="131,375.625 86,375.625 86,393.125 89.25,393.125 89.25,409 84.5,409 84.5,424.5 108.5,424.5 
            108.5,465.75 126.75,465.75 126.75,475 133.875,475 133.875,472.125 147,472.125 147,475 162.625,475 162.625,399.75 131,399.75     
            "/>
        <polygon class="st3" points="61,475 45.125,475 45.125,425.312 65.75,425.312 65.75,409 67.625,409 67.625,375.625 29.375,375.625 
            29.375,372.875 16.26,372.875 14.333,399 14.333,500.75 52.875,500.75 52.875,487.875 61.001,487.875   "/>
        <polygon class="st3" points="52.875,500.75 52.875,505.125 87.125,505.125 87.125,515 108.625,515 108.625,487.75 139.875,487.75 
            139.875,499.5 145.75,499.5 145.75,515 142.875,515 142.875,531.5 149,531.5 149,578 14.333,578 14.333,500.75  "/>
        <polygon class="st3" points="139.875,487.75 202.375,487.75 202.375,499.625 219.25,499.625 219.25,490.5 232.5,490.5 
            232.5,487.75 280,487.75 280,500.75 282.875,500.75 282.875,578 149,578 149,531.5 142.875,531.5 142.875,515 145.75,515 
            145.75,499.5 139.875,499.5  "/>
        <polygon class="st3" points="162.625,475 219.5,475 219.5,472 232.25,472 232.25,475 242,475 242,464.125 257.375,464.125 
            257.375,399.75 162.625,399.75   "/>
        <polygon class="st3" points="257.375,464.125 274.875,464.125 274.875,475 285,475 285,472.5 298.125,472.5 298.125,475 
            366.625,475 366.625,399.5 313.25,399.5 313.25,392.75 293.5,388.5 288,399.75 257.375,399.75  "/>
        <polygon class="st3" points="282.875,500.75 301.875,500.75 301.875,487.75 310.333,487.75 310.333,490.875 323.5,490.875 
            323.5,487.75 366.625,487.75 366.625,527.75 392.25,527.75 392.25,578 282.875,578     "/>
        <polygon class="st3" points="392.25,527.75 392.25,578 465.5,578 465.5,557 468.375,557 468.375,500.75 451.875,500.75 
            451.875,487.75 439.25,487.75 439.25,490.75 426.125,490.75 426.125,487.75 415,487.75 415,527.75  "/>
        <path class="st3" d="M392.25,578"/>
        <polygon class="st3" points="465.5,578 465.5,557 468.375,557 468.375,487.75 505.875,487.75 505.875,490.75 528.25,490.75 
            528.25,475 606.333,475 606.333,578  "/>
        <polygon class="st3" points="366.625,475 418.375,475 418.375,472.625 431.875,472.625 431.875,475 441.75,475 441.75,464.25 
            458.75,464.25 458.75,399.667 432.667,399.667 432.667,392.5 418.75,388.25 399.75,399.5 366.625,399.5     "/>
        <polygon class="st3" points="458.75,399.667 606.333,399.667 606.333,475 519.125,475 519.125,472.375 505.75,472.375 505.75,464 
            490.5,464 490.5,475 458.75,475  "/>
        <polygon class="st3" points="519.125,472.375 519.125,490.75 505.875,490.75 505.875,487.75 439.25,487.75 439.25,490.75 
            426.125,490.75 426.125,487.75 323.5,487.75 323.5,490.875 310.333,490.875 310.333,487.75 232.5,487.75 232.5,490.5 219.25,490.5 
            219.25,487.75 78.375,487.75 78.375,505.125 62.875,505.125 62.875,487.75 61.001,487.75 61.001,475 133.875,475 133.875,472.125 
            147,472.125 147,475 219.5,475 219.5,472 232.25,472 232.25,475 285,475 285,472.5 298.125,472.5 298.125,475 418.375,475 
            418.375,472.625 431.875,472.625 431.875,475 505.875,475 505.875,472.375     "/>
        <line class="st3" x1="384.339" y1="487.75" x2="384.339" y2="500.625"/>
        <polyline class="st3" points="366.625,500.625 401.625,500.625 401.625,504 415,504   "/>
        <line class="st3" x1="401.625" y1="500.625" x2="401.625" y2="487.75"/>
        <polyline class="st3" points="67.625,475 67.625,472.75 66,472.75 66,425.312 84.5,425.312 84.5,475   "/>
        <line class="st3" x1="111.875" y1="465.75" x2="111.875" y2="475"/>
    </g>
    </svg>
```

Comment: There's no z-index in SVG.

Comment: @robert Thanks for that. It amazes me how moving the polygons above the text labels got them to display behind the text (based on the answer below)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply move your text elements above the polygons by reversing the order of the `"units"` and `"labels"` groups:

https://jsfiddle.net/mh946reL/

You may want to change the color of your texts so that they don't disappear in the background when a room is highlighted.

Comment: wow thank you!! How weird is it that the polygons have to come before the labels to stay behind!

Comment: It is not weird at all. SVG is not HTML. In SVG (and any other vector file format) elements that are drawn first will be behind those drawn later. It's called the ["Painter's Algorithm"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Painter%27s_algorithm).  `z-index` is an HTML property, not an SVG one - for now at least. In future versions of SVG, `z-index` will probably be allowed.